# Google Apps Script Date in two column

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I want to concatenate 2 cells to create one date in apps script in order to add an Event to calendar.

```
 function AgendaL13 () {
  var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var feuille1 = classeur.getSheetByName("TABLEAU DE BORD") 
  var sheetNom = feuille1.getRange("D4").getDisplayValue(); //Nom client
  var titre = feuille1.getRange("E5").getDisplayValue(); // title of event
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar(); // default calendar

  var date = feuille1.getRange('H13').getValue(); // date 22/12/2016
  var heure = feuille1.getRange('I13').getValue(); // Hour 18:00

  var dateNew = date+heure;

  cal.createEvent(sheetNom+ " : " +titre, dateNew, dateNew);
}
```

i want datenew = Thu Dec 22 2016 18:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

Is it possible?
Sorry for my bad english (I'm french)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
date.setHours(heure.getHours());
date.setMinutes(heure.getMinutes()); // if you use minutes
date.setSeconds(heure.getSeconds()); // if you use seconds
```

This will set `date`'s time to `heure`'s time.

Answer (score 1):

I was also working on a similar case. This worked for me:

```
function myFunction()
{
  var sheet = SpreadSheetApp.openById("SheetId").getSheetByName("SheetName");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var date = data[rowIndexforDate][columnIndexforDate];
  var time = data[rowIndexforTime][columnIndexforTime];

  var eventTime = setTimeToDate(date,time);

  //after this would be the code for the creation of the event
}

function setTimeToDate(date,time) //this function does the job
{
  var t = time.split(":"); //in my case the time is separated by ":"

  var dateMod = new Date(date.setHours(t[0],t[1],t[2],0));
  return dateMod;
}
```